# Wlan0 not showing up in kali

Tags: kali-linux

So, today I downloaded kali Linux on VMware just to mess around. I noticed that for any sort of wireless attack, I needed a wireless interface, which is wlan0

Problem is, I have no clue how to get wlan0 or anything like that up and running I'm completely new to Ubuntu or Linux or anything as a whole, so I have no real idea what I'm doing

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: here is some info for you to read ... https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a VM, it's a completely isolated environment from your host. Therefore it won't see any of your system devices, like your system wifi adapter, unless you explicitly pass it through into the VM.

By default your VM will likely have been created with a virtual ethernet adapter which allows it to share network access with your host.

If you want to pass your wifi adapter through to the VM, or any other device for that matter, it is not longer usable by the host. They don't share. So if you need your wifi adapter for internet access on your host then pass it through to the VM to use, you won't be able to get to the internet on your host unless your add other wifi adapter or plug in an ethernet cable.

At a guess, your wifi adapter will be a PCIe device, which are more tricky to pass through into VMs than USB devices. If you want to play with wireless attacks in Kali, I suggest you buy a USB wifi adapter and pass that as a USB device to the VM (which is far  easier to do).

Be warned though, to do anything 'fun' with wireless attacks you'll need a wifi adapter which supports monitor mode, so if you get a USB one, ensure it supports that.